# pass the payableAmount amount value outside the click event

Tags: javascript

how can i pass the payableAmount variable value into the amount object I am stucking here not getting global variable inside the function

```
var options = {
    "key": 'rzp_test_sss',
    "amount": "200", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "FeastBy",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "/your_logo.png",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-payment').onclick = function(e){
    var payableAmount = document.formxml[0].razorPayAmount.value;
    alert(payableAmount);
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

pls suggest

Comment: What's your html? make your question clearer or simpler, or we don't know what happened there `document.formxml[0]`.

Comment: Is rzp1.amount = payableAmount; what you need?

Comment: I think this is faulty - document.formxml[0].razorPayAmount.value - It should be - document.forms[0].razorPayAmount.value - or - if your form name is formxml then, it should be - document.formxml.razorPayAmount.value .